# How do you derive the distribution function of $Z$, where $Z$ is some combination of the rv's $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Question: Suppose that you have the random variables $X$ and $Y$ with known distribution functions. How would you derive the distribution function of $Z$, where $Z$ is defined as some combination of $X$ and $Y$.

For instance, suppose that $Z = \dfrac{X}{Y+1}$, would we have $F_Z = \dfrac{F_X}{F_Y+1}$? I can't find the theory that should explain this.

Comment: Let $\phi:(X,Z)\mapsto Z$, then $\Pr(Z\leq z)=\int_{\phi^{-1}((-\infty,z])}f(x,y)dxdy$ where $f(x,y)$ is the PDF of the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$.

Comment: Something's wrong here: As argument approaches $+\infty$, $F_X$ and $F_Y$ both approach 1. Then $F_Z$ approaches 1/2, contrary to the requirements of a CDF.

Comment: Why does this get downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $Z=\dfrac{X}{1+Y}$ then

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Z\leqslant z) &= \mathsf P(\tfrac{X}{1+Y}\leqslant z) \\ &=\mathsf P(X\leqslant z(1+Y)\cap Y>-1)~+~\mathsf P(X\geqslant z(1+Y)\cap Y<-1)\end{align}$$

Next would be an application of the Law of Total Probability, the form of which depends on what is the joint distribution for $X,Y$, and in particular, whether $Y$ is a continuous or discrete random variable.